# Revert to previous value in a HashMap

Tags: hashmap, rust

I'm updating a key-value in a `HashMap` and then saving the `HashMap` to a file. I want to make sure that if saving to the file fails update is reverted. Here is the code I've written ([Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=11c55f9ad1072b8e99125adc5b6ed3c2)):

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::fs;
extern crate serde_json; // 1.0.37

fn save_map_to_file(map: &HashMap<String, String>) -> Result<(), ()> {
    // serialize map to json
    let map_as_string = match serde_json::to_string(map) {
        Ok(json_map) => json_map,
        Err(_) => return Err(()),
    };

    // write the json to a file
    match fs::write("map.bin", map_as_string) {
        Ok(_) => Ok(()),
        Err(_) => Err(()),
    }
}

fn change_map(map: &mut HashMap<String, String>) {
    // save current value in "key1" (if exists)
    let val = map.get("key1");

    // insert a new value to "key1"
    map.insert(String::from("key1"), String::from("value2"));

    // try to save the map to a file
    match save_map_to_file(map) {
        Ok(_) => (),
        Err(_) => {
            // if save fails, revert back to the original value
            match val {
                Some(value) => {
                    // if "key1" existed before the change, revert back to
                    // original value
                    map.insert(String::from("key1"), value.to_string());
                }

                None => {
                    // if "key1" didn't exist before the change, remove the
                    // new "key1"->"value2" record
                    map.remove("key1");
                }
            }
            ()
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut map: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap::new();

    map.insert(String::from("key1"), String::from("value1"));

    change_map(&mut map);

    println!("Map: {:?}", map);
}
```

When I compile this code I get an error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*map` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:24:5
   |
21 |     let val = map.get("key1");
   |               --- immutable borrow occurs here
...
24 |     map.insert(String::from("key1"), String::from("value2"));
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
...
31 |             match val {
   |                   --- immutable borrow later used here
```

I understand this error but I can't figure out what is the right way to revert the value if saving to file failed.

Comment: I didn't know that, that's actually the easiest solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`insert()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.insert) returns the previous value, if any, so your code can be simplified a lot.  This also solves your borrow problem:

```
fn change_map(map: &mut HashMap<&str, String>) {
    let previous = map.insert("key1", String::from("value2"));
    match save_map_to_file(map) {
        Ok(_) => (),
        Err(_) => {
            previous
                .and_then(|previous| map.insert("key1", previous))
                .or_else(|| map.remove("key1"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I’d say that using `and_then` and `or_else` are not idiomatic here. You want to do side effects, not compute new values. I'd use another `match`.

Answer (score 2):

Rust compiler is not happy with this borrow, just get rid of it

```
--- let val = map.get("key1");
+++ let val = map.get("key1").cloned();
```